# Why does javascript localeCompare sort underscores before periods?

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, compare

I'm trying to compare strings for sorting purposes, and I want to sort periods before underscores (because that follows the ASCII table). Any suggestions / explanations as to why localeCompare doesn't do it that way?

As an example, I want tester.java to come before tester_1.java

"apple".localeCompare("tomatoe") returns -1 because apple is smaller
"tester.java".localeCompare("tester_1.java") returns 1 when I want it to return -1

Comment: by `underlines` you mean `underscore` or `underlined text`?

Comment: @A.J: underscores, thanks!

Comment: Which [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) have you used?

Comment: What locales are you specifying?

Comment: @Xufox I'm not using any options. After a quick glance at the options, none jumped out like they would help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean [`.localeCompare()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp) right (this was mispelled in your question)? So which way is your ordering being done? You possibly have them the wrong way around:

```
var array = [ "_a", ".b" ]
array.sort()             // returns [ ".b", "_a" ]
array.sort(function(a,b) { return a.localeCompare(b) }) // returns [ ".b", "_a" ]
array.sort(function(a,b) { return b.localeCompare(a) }) // returns [ "_a", ".b" ]
```

Looking at that under the hood:

```
var str1 = "_a",
    str2 = ".b";

str1.localeCompare(str2)           // 49
str2.localeCompare(str1)           // -49
```

So if you are comparing in the wrong order then it is "reversed"

```
var array = [ ".c", "_a", ".b" ]
array.sort(function(a,b) { return a.localeCompare(b) })  // [ ".b", ".c", "_a" ]
array.sort(function(a,b) { return b.localeCompare(a) })  // [ "_a", ".c", ".b" ]
```

Comment: Your second code block refers to `a` and `b`, but your variables are `str1` and `str2`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes. Too much cut and paste.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: Thanks a lot for your reply!

I'm making a file system, and instead of sorting the files in a directory each time, I just want to insert every new one that is created in the correct location. I want to play tester.java before tester_1.java. I know I have it the right way because it correctly sorts everything else. Any ideas?

Comment: @OfekGila isn't your example: `"tester.java".localeCompare("tester_1.java") ` the reverse of what you are arguing? "tester.java" should come before "tester_1.java", and it **does**.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I'm not sure what you mean. I want apple to go before tomato just like I want tester.java to go before tester_1.java. How come they don't return the same value?

Comment: If you'd like to use ascii string comparisons, use < and > instead. localeCompare uses a natural-ish sort and depends on the implementation by the engine/ browser. 

This means the behavior can be inconsistent and definitely unexpected, as I found out the hard way in my usage/testing. Because of this, I chose not to use localeCompare and used < instead.